# Is the following IPv6 address valid?

Tags: ipv6, data-validation

i'am asking for a friend. Really :-)

Given the exam question:
Is the following IPv6 address valid?

2001:0DDB8:0:0:8:800:200C:417A

[RFC4291: Text Representation of Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291.html#section-2.2)

I say no since the second block has 5 digits. Sure, leadding zeros can be removed.
Could it be valid because in hex notation there are no leading zeros?

Glad to hear your point of view on this.

Comment: Well, it's not valid on Linux. The leading `0` has to be dropped for it to be accepted.

Comment: In this RFC under 2.2.1 it says up to 4 digits. So no, it's not valid.

Comment: Also saying in hex notation there are leading zeros is not right. What you mean is "0x". It is used to indicate that a number is hex. You can have leading zeros in base 10 as well. For example 0100 is simply one hundred.

Comment: Also note that a leading zero in programming sometimes means base 8. For example chmod 0777 is base 8.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not valid. The spaces between the colons may only contain up to 4 characters, which all must be hex digits of course, representing 16 bits of the address. This 5th hex digit suggests 20 bits, which isn't  valid.

Just because you can drop *valid* leading zeroes from this notation doesn't mean you can also pad it with *invalid* leading zeroes.